# Powershell Script to Find SharePoint Groups with [No Access]

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, permissions

Our company is running into an issue post-upgrade with (some) custom SharePoint groups being appended with [No Access] that is throwing group members Access Denied messages when they try to access the site.

Is there a Powershell script that can search through our entire web application for custom SharePoint groups that have been appended with [No Access]?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I know nothing about sharepoint managment with PowerShell. The head Corp IT won't give me access. But check out script repositories like [PoshCode](http://poshcode.org/) or [ScriptCenter](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter) check out other forums too like [PowerShell.com](http://powershell.com/cs/forums/)

Remember don't start off your question with "I need a script."